Antiderivatives via Taylor series and the FT of Calculus
If $f$ is a real function on an interval $[a,b]$ such that

$f$ is computationally tractable on $[a,b]$: you can calculate $f(x)$ to $n$ bits of precision using an algorithm which is polynomial in $n$ (in particular requiring only polynomially many bits of precision for $x$)
$f’$, $f’’$, $f’’’$, etc. are computationally tractable at the endpoints $a$ and $b$, and
the Taylor series for $f$ around $a$ and $b$, when integrated term by term to give an antiderivative power series, both converge over the entire interval $[a,b]$,

then do any theorems exist comparing the computational complexity of calculating the definite integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ by numerical integration over the interval, with the computational complexity of calculating that definite integral by evaluating an antiderivative at $a$ and $b$ and applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? Are conditions known under which one can guarantee that the second method asymptotically outperforms the first?

An example of possible extra conditions: you might need that the radius of convergence is larger than (b-a) because sometimes convergence at an endpoint is slower, or that the successive derivatives don't grow too fast. What I want to understand here is if any of the fuss about the kind of functions that are defined in Calculus classes not being "integrable" (in the sense that the antiderivative does not have an expression in terms of the set of primitive functions and operators that generated the class of functions being treated) corresponds to a real-life computational problem.

What if all derivatives of $f$ vanish at $a$ and $b$ but $f$ has a bump in $(a,b)$?

I should’ve been clearer, not only do the Taylor series of f around a and b converge on [a,b] when integrated term by term, it’s also a requirement that they converge before that, to f.
